# How to locate the span element with Xpath Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

My HTML format is below:

***button class="btn authorize unlocked"

span>Authenticate</span

button***

So when I use "**browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class = "btn authorize unlocked"]')**"
to locate this button, it can not find that.

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class = "btn authorize unlocked"]"}
```

So what should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.authorize.unlocked > span")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn authorize unlocked']/span[text()='Authenticate']")
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.authorize.unlocked > span")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn authorize unlocked']/span[text()='Authenticate']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```